# Scala pipelines - DSL for building a DAG workflow

Tags: scala, functional-programming, akka, pipeline, scalaz

Im curious about the current libraries for Scala & Akka which would allow me to elegantly build a workflow pipeline.

In my case a workflow is just a DAG of operations so actors/Akka feels like a good fit.

My question is what's the best approach? There are Libs like reactive streams which allow really elegant composition of a pipeline but they seem very record focused.

My use case is a flow of operations passing messages between them. Future composition is nice but syntax becomes unwieldy after a while. Maybe there is something better with scalaz and shapeless.

What are the approaches and tools to building a DSL for pipelines of computation steps using message passing?

Comment: Can you explain what it means to be "record focused" and why this isn't appropriate for "passing messages"?  What is the difference between a "record" and a "message" in your eyes?

Comment: Sorry. My pipeline is very much like a chain of method calls. Where parameter passing is a message. The streaming side of Akka seems very focused on taking a stream of data. I.e. Log file. My case would be a log file with 1 line. While it would work. Is it efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your pipeline is very much like a chain of method calls, *use a chain of method calls*!

There's no point making the solution more complicated than it needs to be; if it's well-modelled by a chain of methods calls, just use that.  (Or functions, which you can compose.)

If you need something slightly more complicated but you don't actually need any message-passing, you might want something like [AsyncFP](https://github.com/laforge49/Asynchronous-Functional-Programming) or [Scala.Rx](https://github.com/lihaoyi/scala.rx).

If you need a multi-core solution, but you have stretches that look like method calls, then have a chain of method calls inside one stop.  You could use Akka streams for that without having to worry so much about the overhead to useful computation ratio.

Answer (score 3):

While still in early development (pre 1.0 as of writing), you should have a look at [akka-streams](http://akka.io/news/2014/09/12/akka-streams-0.7-released.html), which are exactly that - a way to describe a computation graph and then run it asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks. The streaming side of Akka seems very focused on taking a stream of data. I.e. Log file. My case would be a log file with 1 line. While it would work. Is it efficient?

Comment: Any examples of streams using a future as a source?

Comment: `Source(Future(42))` :-)